# How to create database and start that database in neo4j from c# backend?

Tags: neo4j, neo4jclient

I am really hopeless how to create database and start that database from c# backend just like neo4j Community.

```
I know how to Assign Neo4j URI
    neoClient = new GraphClient(new Uri("http://localhost:7474/db/data"));

And I know how to connect with Neo4j GraphDB
    neoClient.Connect(); after starting my database using Neo4j Community.

But actually I wanna create a folder(Neo4j Database) from c# backend and
 start that database from c# backend. 
Is it possible to do that using any api(neo4jClient)? Please help me.
```

Comment: Actually I have different different result set and I wanna store that result set in separate location. It may exist in same database also how can I do that please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server gets started pointing at a particular [neostore directory](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/server-configuration.html#_important_server_configuration_parameters).  So when the RESTful services start up, they're implicitly pointing to that directory.  From the REST services side, you can't create a new database on disk; when you connect as you are in your code, you're connecting to a database stored at wherever the server is configured to store those files.

A single graph database can store as many graphs as you want though, and there's nothing wrong with storing a separate disjoint dataset in the same overall graph, so you may want to reconsider whether or not you even need what you're asking for.   You store results in that same graph much as you would in any case, just by [using the REST API](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api.html).